# Using NSKeyedArchiver with Swift Array

Tags: swift

I am trying to save a set of data using NSKeyedArchiver. The data also includes a swift array of Ints. For a test code I convert a simple data set to Data and then covert it back.
Please see my code below. The code works but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this. Thanks.

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let numbers = [3,5,2,43]

let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(requiringSecureCoding: true)
if let dataForNumbers = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: numbers, requiringSecureCoding: true ){
    archiver.encode( dataForNumbers, forKey: "numbers" )
    archiver.encode( str, forKey: "testString")

}
let data = archiver.encodedData
```

convert data back into objects

```
if let unarchiver = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.init(forReadingFrom: data ){
    let numberData = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "numbers" )
    if let numbers = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(numberData as! Data) as? [Int] {
            print( numbers )
        }
    let testString = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "testString") as? String
    print( testString )

}
```

thanks Reza

Comment: `Codable` is nowadays preferred over older `NSCoding`, but if it works...

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are asking about file size and speed you can save your string utf8 data to a text file and your array of integers raw data to a binary file as follow:

---

```
let str = "Hello, playground"
let numbers = [3, 5, 2, 43]

if let textURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("str.txt"),
   let fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("numbers.bin") {
    do {
        
        let strData = Data(str.utf8)
        try strData.write(to: textURL)

        let numbersData = numbers.withUnsafeBytes { Data($0) }
        try numbersData.write(to: fileURL)
        
        let stringFromData = try String(contentsOf: textURL)
        let loadedNumbersData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        
        let numbersFromLoadedData = loadedNumbersData.withUnsafeBytes { [Int]($0.bindMemory(to: Int.self))
        }
        
        print(stringFromData)
        print(numbersFromLoadedData)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

---

This will print:

> Hello, playground
> [3, 5, 2, 43]